# undefined method `admin?' for #

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good afternoon,

I am attempting to fix I am having with my rails application.

Heres a direct image to the issue:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2z6v5w2.jpg

here is my topic_policy.rb

```
class TopicPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

def index?
true
end

def create?
user.present? && user.admin?
end

def update?
create?
end
end
```

Here is my application_policy.rb

```
class ApplicationPolicy
attr_reader :user, :record

def initialize(user, record)
@user = user
@record = record
end

def index?
false
end

def show?
scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
end

def create?
user.present?
end

def new?
create?
end

def update?
user.present? && (record.user == user || user.admin?)
end

def edit?
update?
end

def destroy?
update?
end

def scope
record.class
end

class Scope
attr_reader :user, :scope

def initialize(user, scope)
@user = user
@scope = scope
end

def resolve
scope
end
end
end
```

And here is the topics_controller.rb

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
def index
@topics = Topic.all
authorize @topics
end

def new
@topic = Topic.new
authorize @topic
end

def show
@topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
authorize @topic
end

def edit
@topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
authorize @topic
end

def create
@topic = Topic.new(params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :description, :public))
authorize @topic
if @topic.save
redirect_to @topic, notice: "Topic was saved successfully."
else
flash[:error] = "Error creating topic. Please try again."
render :new
end
end

def update
@topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
authorize @topic
if @topic.update_attributes(params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :description, :public))
redirect_to @topic
else
flash[:error] = "Error saving topic. Please try again"
render :edit
end
end
end
```

I am just attempting to get it to view a web page through my rails app, but I am stuck.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Please clarify where the authorize command is defined? Is this from a gem?

Comment: User model code would be useful as well.

Comment: Where is the 'admin?' Method defined. Does it come from a gem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by making the admin method public, it was set to private.